# Remove regex from query MongoDB - C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using the following code in C# to acquire data from MongoDB database:

```
var result = GetItemsByQuery(Query<Table1>
  .Where(p => p.Field1.ToLower() == string1.ToLower()));
```

But this produces that MongoDB uses regex and I want to avoid that. I know that I should use collation, but I am not sure how to fix this line with that. Or is there another way that won't use regex?

Comment: Yes, I am using MongoDB.Driver.Builders

Comment: Can you show the `GetItemsByQuery` method?

Comment: I can't because I imported it from .dll file so I don't have any clue about it :( I thought it is something common

Comment: Does the method have any other parameters, e.g. some `FindOptions`? These are used to set the collation of the query.

Comment: No, Query is the only parameter

Comment: Can you get the `IMongoCollection<T>` and use `Find` directly?

Comment: Yes, I can import MongoCollection and then I should use the find with settings so I can use collation?

Comment: Yes, this way you have the greatest flexibility and can use all the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the library method `GetItemsByQuery`, you should get an `IMongoCollection<T>` instance for the collection. As soon as you have the collection, you can use the `Find` method (or its async counterparts `FindAsync`) and specify the collation, e.g.:

```
IMongoCollection<Table1> coll = ...
var collation = new Collation("en_US");
var options = new FindOptions<Table1>() 
{
  Collation: collation,
};
var result = coll.Find(x => x.Field1 == string1, options);
```

The [`Collation`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_FindOptionsBase_Collation.htm) property was added in driver version 2.4.